# How i can reproduce this format?

Tags: php, date, datetime

How i can reproduce this date format with php?

```
2016-04-07T09:03:32
```

I'm using:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', time());
```

But i don't know what is The 'T' printed beetween date and time

Comment: Try and do a little research, for example php's docs for the function date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What youre looking for is:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d\Th:i:s', time());
```

The 'T' is for [HTML5 local date-time](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.datetime-local.html) required format.

If you want to use this format to be sure of compatability, you should use the constant to speficy the format which includes the timezone offset between local and GMT.

```
$date = date(DateTime::ATOM, time());
```

which will output:

> 2016-04-07T01:20:48-07:00

Answer (score 0):

The T designates the start of a time string in the [ISO 8601 date format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

You can reproduce this format using [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) like this:

```
date('c')
```

But note this will (and *should*) also include the timezone offset. Because the date string will always be the same format you remove this quite easily to match your specified format with [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) like so:

```
$date = date('c');
$formattedDate = substr($date, 0, 19);
```